# Extra alignment tab to \cr

Tags: tables, alignment

I am facing the above error when dealing with the following table. I cannot find extra "\" or missing ones. Can you please help me figure out the reason for such an error?

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{\footnotesize First stage results at different levels. \\ ATC-3 aggregation represents the main specification. \label{fiststage}}
\scalebox{0.6}{ \vspace*{-0.01mm}\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(ATC-Firm Aggregation)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(ATC-3 Aggregation)}} \\
                         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Log sales}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Log sales}\\
\midrule
$\tilde{recalls}$         &     -0.0053         &    -0.0283\sym{***}\\
                          &    (0.0033)         &    (0.0056)         \\
$\tilde{recalls}_{t-1}$   &     -0.0267\sym{**} &     -0.0267\sym{***}\\
                          &    (0.0083)         &    (0.0070)         \\
$\frac{K_{t+1}}{P_{-1}}$  &                     &      0.1932\sym{**} \\
                          &                     &    (0.0628)         \\
\textit{average age firm}
                          &                     &       0.1576         \\
                         
                           &                     &    (0.0921)         \\
\textit{aaf}$^{2}$.        &                   &  -0.0020         \\
                           &                     &    (0.0013)         \\
hhi                       &                     &      1.2405\sym{***}\\
                           &                     &    (0.2590)         \\
\textit{share generics in ATC}
                           &                     &     -0.1895         \\
                         
                           &                     &    (0.3373)         \\
papers                     &                     &     -0.0260         \\
                           &                     &    (0.0507)         \\
\textit{\# firms}        
                          &                      &      0.0077         \\
                        
                        &                     &    (0.0071)         \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Year Dummies} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} \\                                            \midrule  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Obs.}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{48915} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1664} \\                                                                                        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Groups} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8634} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{208} \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}
\end{tabular}}\begin{spacing}{0.1}\vspace{0.3cm} \footnotesize  {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont}{\Huge }{\begin{minipage}{11.6cm}\tiny Huber-White robust and clustered at ATC-3 level standard errors are in parentheses. First-stage results are shown in this Table. (1) fits an F.E. model at ATC-Firm level, i.e., ATC lines of productions within firms. This level is introduced to check the possibility of compensations between sales of products belonging to the same ATC (excluded due to the significance of the coefficient of recalls witnessing a drop after a recall) (2) fits an F.E. model at the ATC-3 level. $\tilde{recalls}$ represent recalls normalized. At the ATC level, recalls are respectively normalized for the number of products within an ATC. \end{minipage}} \\ {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont}  \end{spacing}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please post a *complete* example. Not everybody has time to try and guess all packages needed to type this table.

Comment: The first thing to do is probably to align all `&` and `\\ ` in your code. It will be far easier to spot the reason for your problem then.

Comment: I guess the culprit are the multicolumn commands. You have some that span 5 columns, but you only declare 3 columns.

Comment: I see. It was it indeeed!